# Find associated object if exists, otherwise generate it

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a simplified model that looks like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks

  def pick_for_game(game)
    id = game.instance_of?(Game) ? game.id : game
    pick = picks.find {|pick| pick.game_id == id}
    if !pick
      pick = picks.build(:game_id => id)
    end
    pick
  end
end
```

The `pick_for_game` method usually is called a bunch of times when an action is executed. What would be a good way to make this code work efficiently with a list of games?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `find_or_initialize_by` dynamic finder, see a guide [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)

This would be equivalent to your code:

```
def pick_for_game(game)
  game_id = game.instance_of?(Game) ? game.id : game
  picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(game_id)
end
```

Hope it helps you!.

Comment: This is why I love ruby and rails. You can write such elegant and simple code.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @jpemberthy: Shouldn't we duck type?

```
def pick_for_game(game)
  game = game.id if game.respond_to? :id
  picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(game)
end
```

or be brazen:

```
def pick_for_game(game)
  picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(begin game.id rescue game end)
end
```